# Adding the last two elements of a list

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In Mathematica, what is the cleanest way of taking a list

```
{r1, r2, r3, ..., rn, a, b}
```

and returning

```
{r1, r2, r3, ..., rn, a + b}
```

or more generally

```
{r1, r2, r3, ..., rn, f[a, b]}
```

for some function `f`?

Comment: Simon, I expected a beginner to be asking this question, not you.  What precisely are you after?  Let me rephrase that: by what metric will you evaluate the replies?  Execution speed?  Shortest code?  Most easily readable to Mathematica novices?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Just the cleanest/clearest code. I came up with a few options, but wasn't happy with most of them. So I thought that maybe someone else has a better idea. And they did - for some reason I had completely blanked on using `ReplaceAll`!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Anyway - I thought it might be a nice simple/fun question after all of the murky digging in Mma's internals that has been going on!

Comment: +1, for making me think I had a simple solution, `MapAt`, and then discovering that it clearly did not do what you asked for ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lst = {a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a, b}; 
lst /. {a___, b_, c_} -> {a, f[b, c]}

 ==> {a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], f[a, b]}
```

or (ugly):

```
Append[Take[lst, {1, -3}], f @@ lst[[{-2, -1}]]]
```

Comment: Thanks Sjoerd! The first solution probably wants to use `RuleDelayed` instead of `Rule`. Also the last one can be slightly prettified as `Append[lst[[1;;-3]], f@@lst[[-2;;-1]]]`. (of course, beauty is in the eye of the beholder and all that)

Comment: btw: I had completely blanked about `ReplaceAll` when looking at this problem, so all of my solutions were like your second (ugly) one.

Comment: Interestingly your "ugly" method is a little faster than mine, but I thought (in the past) I tested similar operations and found the form I posted to be faster.  I guess not.  Maybe I was able to do in-place manipulation at that time.

Comment: You get the "tick" since `/.` is visually the clearest and your "ugly" solution is (according to @Mr.W) the fastest!

Answer (score 3):

I'd use rules if performance is not a big issue (lists are not packed etc):

```
 lst = {a, b, c, d, e}

 In[13]:= Replace[lst, {left__, ntl_, l_} :> {left, f[ntl, l]}, {0}]

 Out[13]= {a, b, c, f[d, e]}
```

Comment: Leonid, is the last part of your code: `, {0}` doing anything?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, it does. It makes sure that the replacement is only done on expression itself and not any of its parts. I find this a useful idiom in many cases, when you want to bullet-proof your rule-based solutions. In comparison, `ReplaceAll` often leads to bugs when rules are matched on a different level of expression than planned.

Comment: But `Replace` already has that property, does it not?  `Replace[{1, 2, 3}, _Integer -> "x"]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Apparently you are right, I just checked the docs. I often use it with a different level spec, like `{1}` or `{2}`, so I probably got a habit of using it explicitly. Unnecessary here, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

If I hadn't second guessed Simon I would have been first to answer. Nuts. Anyway, here is my late-to-the-party reply.

```
combineLast =
  Module[{x = #},
    x[[-2]] = #2 @@ x[[-2 ;;]];
    Most[x]
  ] &;
```

Comparison:

```
leoCL[lst_, f_] := Replace[lst, {left__, ntl_, l_} :> {left, f[ntl, l]}, {0}]

a = RandomInteger[1*^9, 5000];

Do[combineLast[a, Plus], {5000}] // Timing
Do[leoCL[a, Plus], {5000}] // Timing
```

```
{0.078, Null}

{1.844, Null}
```

Comment: Wow! Your computer is MUCH faster than mine! If you want a little more speed, then the list slicing `[[-2;;]]` can be replaced with the more explicit `[[{-2, -1}]]`.

Comment: @Simon, it shouldn't be faster; this is an old machine using an entry-level processor.  What version of Mathematica are you using?  I am not surprised if `[[{-2, -1}]]` is faster, but my love of terseness won.

Comment: I'm running `8.0.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit)` on a dual core AMD Turion 64 X2 in a low-end HP laptop.

Comment: @Simon I wonder why this is slow on your machine. I just tried `[[{-2, -1}]]` and it is too close to call, another indication that behavior differs.  I seem to recall someone on MathGroup complaining that Mma 8 was slow.  Is is possible for you to try this operation on Mma 7?  Did you do any speed comparisons when you got Mma 8?

Comment: @Simon @Mr. It's twice as fast as on my brand new i7 laptop 8-(  (mma v8)

Comment: @Sjoerd (sorry, can't read, ignore first question)  And do you mean twice as fast as my timings?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Can't read which question? Anyway, your timings are twice as fast as mine.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: The v7 and v8 timings are almost identical. Though it's strange that when I first ran your `combineLast` code your machine was about 6 times faster and the `leoCL` code took forever. Now `combineLast` and `leoCL` are 2.3 and 2.9 times faster on your machine...

Comment: @Sjoerd sorry for the confusion.  I had asked you what version you were running, before realizing that you already said mma v8, so I edited out that part.

Comment: @Simon @Sjoerd, I find it strange that my old machine outperforms yours.  Now I am curious.  I am going to run a benchmark and post the results.  If either of you can do the same in Mathematica 7, I would like to see the numbers.  Maybe my machine is only fast on a few operations.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I left MMA 7 on my previous laptop, and am running mma 8 on my new one. So I guess it doesn't make sense for me to run both.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Got closed way to quick! Probably best to post it on the [Mma tag chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/628/mathematica-tag).

Comment: Interesting to me: [[-2;;]] --- Can't recall ever coming across that syntax before. @Simon -- What would make [[-2;;]] slower?

Comment: @tele that uses `Span`.  See: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Span.html

Comment: @telefunkenvf14 I didn't see your edit the first time.  In my limited testing using Span was not significantly slower in practical cases.  It is a call to another function, rather than direct input to part, so in cases of many applications to a short list, it is slightly slower.  `a = Range[5];` Then 
`First@Timing@Do[a[[-2 ;;]], {5000000}]` is a little slower than `First@Timing@Do[a[[{-2, -1}]], {5000000}]` but again, one is usually working with longer lists.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose 'list' is defined:

```
Remove[list];
list = {r1, r2, r2, r4, r5, a, b};
```

Re-set 'list' to be {r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, a} with the [[-1]] replaced by the sum of the last two elements in 'list'.

```
list = ReplacePart[Drop[list, -1], -1 -> Plus @@ list[[-2 ;; -1]]]
```

Thanks for asking this, btw. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on it:

```
addLastTwo = Function[Append[Drop[#, -2], Total[Take[#, -2]]]];

In[225]:= addLastTwo[{r1, r2, r3, r4, r5}]

Out[225]= {r1, r2, r3, r4 + r5}
```

This is slightly faster than Mr.Wizard's solution, although less general:

```
In[226]:= Do[addLastTwo@a, {10000}] // Timing

Out[226]= {0.25, Null}

In[227]:= Do[combineLast[a, Plus], {10000}] // Timing

Out[227]= {0.39, Null}
```